# Python UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters

Tags: python, python-2.7

There is a json data which contains some Chinese characters.

```
{
  "font_size": "47",
  "sentences": [
    "你好",
    "sample sentence1",
    "sample sentence2",
    "sample sentence3",
    "sample sentence4",
    "sample sentence5",
    "sample sentence6",
    "sample sentence7",
    "sample sentence8",
    "sample sentence9"
  ]
}
```

I create a `Flask` app and use it to receive above json data. I use below curl command to post data.

```
curl -X POST \
  http://0.0.0.0:5000/ \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: af380f7a-42a8-cfbb-9177-74bb348ce5ed' \
  -d '{
  "font_size": "47",
  "sentences": [
    "你好",
    "sample sentence1",
    "sample sentence2",
    "sample sentence3",
    "sample sentence4",
    "sample sentence5",
    "sample sentence6",
    "sample sentence7",
    "sample sentence8",
    "sample sentence9"
  ]
}'
```

After I receive json data from `request.data`, I convert it to json, in fact `request.data` is `str`.

```
json_data = json.loads(request.data)
```

Then I want to format a string with `json_data`.

```
subtitles.format(**json_data)
```

I got an error.

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-1: ordinal not in range(128)

How to solve it? Thanks in advance.

## EDIT

`subtitles` is read from file.

```
subtitles_file = "{path}/templates/sorry/subtitles.ass".format(path=root_path)
with open(subtitles_file, 'r') as file:
     subtitles = file.read()
```

## EDIT Python 2 or Python 3

I'm using python 2 and this error occurs. However Python 3 can automatically handle this. So enjoy Python 3.

Comment: Possibly?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20

Comment: Yes I know this link however I don't know how to fix my program. Maybe I am stupid.

Comment: Where is `subtitles` defined. Try encoding it as a unicode string and then formatting

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? For many problems it doesn't make a difference, but for Unicode encoding problems, it's usually critically important.

Comment: Also, if this _is_ Python 2, is there a reason you're using Python 2? Because if you just use the current version, these problems will go away automatically. (Also, Python 3 is the primary supported version for Flask, and most other packages nowadays.)

Comment: I've added the python-2.7 tag based on your comment on my answer, but in the future, please add it yourself when you think it will be relevant, and especially when someone directly asks you in the comments.

Comment: @CoXier: Did you try putting `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top?

Comment: @Vimanyu That might be the issue if either `subtitles` or `request.data` were literals in the source code, but one comes from a file and the other from a Flask request, and as far as I can tell there are no non-ASCII characters in his actual code.

Comment: @abarnert I will add relevant tag net time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python 2, when you `open` and `read` a file, what you get is a regular `str`, not a `unicode`.

Meanwhile, even if `request.data` is a `str` rather than a `unicode`, if any of the strings in it are non-ASCII, `json_data` will contain `unicode`.

So, when you do `subtitles.format`, that's going to try to `encode` each `unicode` using your default encoding—which, if you haven't done anything, is ASCII. Which will give exactly this error.

The simplest fix is to change `subtitles` to a `unicode`. Like this:

```
with open(subtitles_file, 'r') as file:
    subtitles = file.read().decode('utf-8')
```

… or:

```
with codecs.open(subtitles_file, 'r', 'utf-8') as file:
    subtitles = file.read()
```

(I'm guessing that you want UTF-8; if your files are in some other encoding, obviously use that instead.)

Comment: Very nice answer. Thanks a lot.